# Enum class for weight units

Tags: c++, enum, qt, unit-conversion

I have some enum classes for units, like Weight units (KG and LB). I am translating the code to Qt C++ from Java, and I'm wondering what the best way to do this is as enums cannot have constructors in C++ that same way they do in Java (as far as I know).

Here is the Java class:

> ```
> public enum WeightUnit {
>   LB(WEIGHT_UNIT_LB, 0.45359237), //"lb" 1lb = 0.45359237 kg.
>   KG(WEIGHT_UNIT_KG, 1.0);        //"kg"
>
>   private String displayName;
>   private double scale;
>
>   private WeightUnit(String displayNameKey, double scale) {
>       this.displayName = getDataMessages().getString(displayNameKey);
>       this.scale = scale;
>   }
>
>   public String getDisplayName() {
>       return displayName;
>   }
>
>   public String toString() {
>       return displayName;
>   }
>
>   public static WeightUnit valueByName(String unitName) {
>       for (WeightUnit value : WeightUnit.values()) {
>           if (value.getDisplayName().equals(unitName) ||
>                   value.name().equals(unitName)) {
>               return value;
>           }
>       }
>       throw new IllegalArgumentException(unitName);
>   }
>
>   public static double convert(double value, WeightUnit from, WeightUnit to) {
>       if (from == to) return value;
>       return value * from.scale/to.scale;
>   }
> }
> ```

Here is my C++ translation. It is not as elegant or clean as the Java version.

```
class WeightUnit {
  public:
    enum Value
    {
        LB,
        KG
    };

    WeightUnit() = default;
    constexpr WeightUnit(Value weightUnit) : value(weightUnit) {}

    bool operator==(WeightUnit a) const { return value == a.value; }
    bool operator!=(WeightUnit a) const { return value != a.value; }

    static double convert(double value, WeightUnit fromUnit, WeightUnit toUnit){
        return value * val(fromUnit.value)/val(toUnit.value);
    }

    static WeightUnit fromStr(QString str){
        if (str.compare(toStr(Value::LB)) == 0)
            return WeightUnit::LB;
        else if (str.compare(toStr(Value::KG)) == 0)
            return WeightUnit::KG;
        else
            throw QException();
    }

    static QString toStr(WeightUnit unit){
        if (unit == WeightUnit::LB)
            return "lb";
        else if (unit == WeightUnit::KG)
            return "kg";
        else
            throw QException();
    }

private:
    Value value;

    static double val(Value value){
        switch(value){
        case KG:
            return 1.0;
        case LB:
            return 0.45359237; //1 lb = 0.45359237 kg
        }
        throw QException(); //if not found, throw exception
    }
};
```

Is there any better way to tie values to each enum value in C++? In Java it is easy, because you can specify a constructor that requires certain parameters so you can be sure each enum value has an appropriate String and double value. Is there a way to do this in Qt/C++?

Comment: Would you give some use examples? In what context will you manipulate weight units? If they're used as tags for numeric values, or in a conversion mechanism, I believe there are better options at your disposal than enums.

Comment: They definitely function as enums, ie are passed around, written to a file and read back, selected by users in Settings, etc. Perhaps I should not be combining the enum and conversion functions in C++ since it is not OO in the same way Java is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if Java and C++ display some similarities, particularly in the syntax, they are widely different languages and translating one into the other isn't automatic. Java is chiefly object-oriented, while C++ is more of a multi-paradigm language; one could even argue that it's drifting away from the object-oriented model towards a more functional approach designed to take advantage of compile-time customization and calculations.

So, it's best to take a step back and think again about your objectives and the means you have to achieve them when you transition from one to the other.

What you seem to need is a mapping between a unit, a textual representation and a floating precision proportion. Java allows for `float` based `enum`s, which are thus a good candidate -even if the textual representation needs to be addressed somewhere else- but C++ doesn't. On the other hand, in the most recent version of the C++ standard, you can create and manipulate arrays at compile-time:

```
constexpr std::pair<std::string_view, float> weight_units[] {
    { "kg", 1. },
    { "lb", 0.45359237 },
    { "oz", 0.028349523125 },
};

constexpr auto weight_unit_value(std::string_view unit) {
    return std::find_if(std::begin(weight_units), std::end(weight_units), [unit](auto uv) {
        return uv.first == unit;
    })->second;
}
```

This code sadly compiles only with the latest version of clang, because gcc hasn't implemented the `constexpr` version of the standard algorithms yet. But writing it by hand would take 5 minutes. Or you can simply remove the `constexpr` qualifier.

This code has several advantages over the original Java version, the most important being that everything is defined once in one place. If you want to create a new unit in the original code, you need to modify the `enum` and create a new object with a custom name; here, you just extend the array.

Now, the array is also very handy if you want to parse a weight from a string, or convert a weight to a string:

```
// ex: float weight = parse_weight("1204.3 lb");
auto parse_weight(std::string_view weight) {
    auto coeff =  std::find_if(std::begin(weight_units), std::end(weight_units), [weight](auto uv) {
        return weight.ends_with(uv.first);
    })->second;
    return std::stof(weight.data()) * coeff;
}

auto to_string(float value, std::string_view unit_name) {
    auto result = std::to_string(value / weight_unit_value(unit_name));
    auto out = std::back_inserter(result);
    *out++ = ' ';
    std::copy(unit_name.begin(), unit_name.end(), out);
    return result;
}
```

Error handling could be added very easily (`auto found = std::find_if(...); if (found == std::end(units)) throw unknown_unit("blabla");`

Here's some code to toy with: https://wandbox.org/permlink/zj0hckfk6jR0vrXT

Comment: Thank you for the example code, this seems much cleaner than what I was doing.